# Binary Search Tree : Insertion

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree, treenode

I am working on the exercise Binary Search Tree : Insertion on HackerRank. Here is the problem statement:

You are given a pointer to the root of a binary search tree and a value to be inserted into the tree. Insert this value into its appropriate position in the binary search tree and return the root of the updated binary tree. You just have to complete the function.

I submitted the following solution and passed 4 of 6 test cases and failed 2 of 6 test cases the problem is i am not able to see the two test cases that failed so i am not sure as to why they are failing. I have tried to create my own test cases and they seemed to be working correctly. Can you think of any test cases that my solution would not work for? I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction

```
 /* Node is defined as :
class Node 
int data;
Node left;
Node right;

*/

static Node Insert(Node root,int value)
{
   if (root == null){
       root = new Node();
       root.data = value;
       return root;
   }
   ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
   list.add(root);
   getNode(list,value);
   return root;
}

static void getNode(ArrayList<Node> list,int value){
    ArrayList<Node> newList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        newList.add(list.get(i).left);
        newList.add(list.get(i).right);
        if(list.get(i).left == null){
            list.get(i).left = new Node();
            list.get(i).left.data = value;
            return;
        }
        if(list.get(i).right == null){
            list.get(i).right = new Node();
            list.get(i).right.data = value;
            return;
        }
    }
    getNode(newList,value);
}
```

Comment: In a binary tree greater values normally "go to the right" and smaller ones to the left. I don't see you comparing values anywhere. You just take the first free leaf-node. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion for an example of insertion.

Comment: ok yes that makes sense, i did not know that i have not used binary trees before i was under the impression that you just needed to traverse from left to right, top to bottom and insert 'value' into the first empty node. This helps a lot thanks

Answer (score 0):

static Node Insert(Node root,int value)
    {

```
   if(root == null)
   {
       Node new_node = new Node();
       new_node.data=value;
       root = new_node;
   }

if(value < root.data)
    {
    if(root.left != null)
        {
        Node.Insert(root.left,value);
    }
    else
        {
        Node new_node = new Node();
        new_node.data = value;
        root.left=new_node;
    }

}
if(value > root.data)
    {
    if(root.right !=null)
        {
         Node.Insert(root.right,value);
    }
    else
        {
        Node new_node = new Node();
        new_node.data=value;
        root.right=new_node;
    }

}
return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic implementation of binary tree ..hope this helps you

```
 class Node {

  Integer data;

  Node left;

  Node right;

  Node(Integer data) {

    this.data=data;

    left=null;

    right=null;

  }

}

public class BinarySearchTree {

  private Node root;

  private Node searchElement;

  public BinarySearchTree() {

  root=null;

}

public void insert(Integer data) {

    if(root==null) {

        root=new Node(data);

        System.out.println("root");

                }else {

    root=insert(data,root);

    }

}

public Node insert(Integer data,Node traverse) {

    if(traverse==null){

        traverse=new Node(data);

                }

    else if(data<traverse.data){

        traverse.left=insert(data,traverse.left);

            }

    else {

        traverse.right=insert(data,traverse.right);

            }

    return traverse;

}


public Node search(int element,Node traverse) {

    if(traverse==null) {

        System.out.println("Element not found");

        return traverse;

    }else if(element<traverse.data) {

        traverse.left=search(element,traverse.left);

        return traverse;

    }else if(element>traverse.data) {

        traverse.right=search(element,traverse.right);

        return traverse;

    }else if(element==traverse.data) {

        System.out.println("element found");

        System.out.println(traverse);

        return traverse;

    }

    return traverse;

}

public void search(int element) {

    searchElement=search(element,root);

}

public static void main(String... args){

    BinarySearchTree bst=new      BinarySearchTree();

    bst.insert(10);

    bst.insert(12);

    bst.insert(6);

    bst.insert(100);

    bst.search(12);

}

}
```

Comment: It is nice to you to help with this piece of code, but the original poster asked for something slightly different; did you notice something wrong in his/her code?